# Loop thru values code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is what I’m trying to do: 
When an order is created, click view link and and get redirected to the show page which contains the invoice.  I'm using the below code to loop thru values in the invoice. But its not working correctly, all invoices are showing up instead of only the selected one. 
I already tried deleting the `<% @orders.each do |order| %>` but without any luck.

What am I missing here? Any idea?

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
<% order.line_items.each do |line_item| %>
Order #<%= line_item.order_id %>
<%= order.first_name %> <%= order.last_name %>
<%= line_item.product.title %>
<%= number_to_currency line_item.product.price %>
<%= line_item.quantity %>
<%= number_to_currency line_item.total_price %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Update 1**

route.rb: `resources :orders, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show]`

I don't have an invoice controller, everything is going thru the orders controller.

```
  def show
    @orders = Order.all
  end

 def new
    @cart = current_cart
    if @cart.line_items.empty?
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Your cart is empty"
    return 
    end

   @order = Order.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb 
      format.json { render json: @order }
   end
  end


  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)
    @order.user_id = current_user.id

      if @order.save
      if @order.process
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Successfully charged." 
      and      
      return
      end
    end
    render 'new'
  end
```

Comment: Could you post what the route looks like that you are using to view this page and post your invoice controller.  The problem has do with the @orders variable, you need it to be just the order with the id clicked, which would usually be set by the route and grabbed by the controller.

Comment: @Rockwell Rice thanks for the response!! Please check update 1 for more details.

Comment: As I mention in my answer, make sure the route has the order's id in it and you should be good to go after the other changes.

Comment: there will be a default route for show if we added resources :orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method In Controller to

```
 def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
 end
```

and in views remove

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
```

and call the order attributes by

```
<% @order.line_items.each do |line_item| %>
  Order #<%= line_item.order_id %>
  <%= @order.first_name %> <%= @order.last_name %>
  <%= line_item.product.title %>
  <%= number_to_currency line_item.product.price %>
  <%= line_item.quantity %>
  <%= number_to_currency line_item.total_price %>
<% end %>
```

you were showing all the orders instead you only need to show order that got created in latest.

Comment: resources :orders  will create default route for show.

Answer (score 0):

@Theopap

The issue currently is the show method which returns the all the orders found in the Order database, refactor the show method to look for orders of a specific id, therefore your show method should look something like this:

**Current show should become index action**

```
def index
  @orders = Order.all
end
```

**This will get the order id from the route, so the**

```
def show
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end
```

**Routes**

Something like this should done with your routes so that your params[id].

`get ‘\order\:id’, to:‘order#show’`

Better still use the option below to generate the 7 default rails actions.e.g. index, show, create etc. 
`resources orders` (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/routing.html)

Comment: **Iteration of one object**
```
  <% @order.line_items.each do |line_item| %>
     Order #<%= line_item.order_id %>
     <%= @order.first_name %> <%= @order.last_name %>
     <%= line_item.product.title %>
     <%= number_to_currency line_item.product.price %>
     <%= line_item.quantity %>
     <%= number_to_currency line_item.total_price %>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Show method needs to look like this

```
def show
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end
```

Make sure the route has the id in it, it should look like this where ":id" is a number (most likely)

```
/orders/:id
```

If the route doe snot look like that change the route in the link to that, 
probably something like the **params[:id]** bit is grabbing that id from the route and that is how it finds that specific order.

In your view you will not need to do the each loop.  You will be able to use the @order variable you create, so your view would look like this

```
<%= @order.first_name %> <%= @order.last_name %>
```

Answer (score -4):

Could you please display your show method, the issue is likely to be from there. Use the ruby on rails debugger in the mean time, to ensure that @orders contains the invoice information for just the order placed.

try this: <%= debug @orders %>

Comment: thanks for the response!! Please check update 1 for more details.

Comment: Please use comment to ask for additional info.

Comment: @MotKohn thanks for the headup, will do in the future, learning how to use the platform.